# What's wrong with my Atom Editor Snippet?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm getting to know Atom. I tried to make a snippet with the following format:

```
 'text.html.basic':
  'Comment Class':
    'prefix': '<.'
    'body': '<!-- .$1 -->'
```

But when I type `<.` then the `tab` key, nothing happens.  Why not?

Comment: Just a guess: nonWordCharacters are invalid for prefixes

Comment: Yup, had the same problem and this is still true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atom currently only supports alphanumeric characters for snippet prefixes, see the open issue at https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-snippets/issues/56

Try using a prefix such as "comment" and it should work. I unfortunately don't know a better workaround.

Comment: I guess that's the answer, and that's too bad. That's enough for me to not use this editor.  Back to Sublime Text!