# Atom Snippet for HTML doesn't run

Tags: html, windows, atom-editor

I have an html snippet in my `snippets.cson` file in my atom text editor for windows, it doesn't give me any errors but when I open my `index.html` file and begin to type the prefix nothing appears.

My expectation is that I should type `<!DOC` and then see the start page snippet pop up, hitting tab will auto generate my page template.

What am I doing wrong, right now nothing happens.

```
# Snippet for opening a new html page
 'text.html.basic':
    'start page':
        'prefix': '<!DOC'
        'body': """
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title></title>
                    <link rel='stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href='css/' />
                </head>
                <body>
                    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
                               integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
                               crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                    <script src = 'javascript/'></script>
                </body>
             </html>
                """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the snippet to be relevant for `.html` files you should use

```
.text.html.basic
```

In the first line (and **not** `.html`).

**Update from the comments**:

> Note that you can't use `<!` in the prefix. You can change the prefix to `DOC` and it will work.

Comment: Did you restart Atom after the change?

Comment: Yep, just did same thing

Comment: I found the answer, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35121599/whats-wrong-with-my-atom-editor-snippet

Comment: I can't have `<!` in the prefix, it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't work. Changing my prefix to `DOC` works fine. Please modify your answer to reflect this so that I can give you  proper credit, you did half fix :-)